# Check if user has restaurant 48hours after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, sidekiq

I have some trouble to check if my user have created a restaurant 48 hours after signed_up ( the objective is to send an Email reminder).

I tried differents things and right now i'm with this in my

**USER MODEL : User.rb**

```
after_create :reminder



def reminder
    if Time.now.utc == self.created_at + 48.hours && self.restaurants.count == 0
    UserMailer.theactionofthemail(self).deliver_later
 end
```

I tried it like this because i saw that with sidekiq i didn't have to create job to deliver_later my UserMailers .. :)

Any Clues ? 
If it's not clear tell me !

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`after_create` will call that method immediately after create, so created_at will never be equal (BTW, usually you want to say >=, just in case milliseconds have passed) to the users's created_at.

Instad I suggest you explore ActiveJob. Create a job that does this same question, except is ran 48 hours later:

```
after_create :reminder

def reminder
  CreateRestaurantReminderJob.set(wait: 48.hours).perform_later self
end
```

In that job:

```
def perform(user)
  return unless user.restaurants.count.zero?
  UserMailer.theactionofthemail(user).deliver_now
end
```

If you are already using Sidekiq, you can configure it as the backend for ActiveJob, or use it's own workers. The syntax might change, but the same concept stands.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer , i'll try this now :)

Comment: If i understand well, the mail is sent and is waiting 48 hours. 
And the job is checking each ( 15 seconds for default sidekiq) if the user has created a restaurant ?

Comment: I've updated the code example to be more clear: The `CreateRestaurantReminderJob` is enqueued immediately after the user is created, and it's set to run only after 48 hours have passed (no email sent so far). When the worker runs, it asks: "Has this user created a restaurant yet?", if not, it sends the email right there.